# using a datatemplate on Polylines

Tags: wpf, binding, datatemplate, polyline

i try to Bind a X and Y out of Observablecolletion.Points directly with Datatemplate. Reason is I want to use converter on X and Y later on. I did the Binding like this.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Measurements}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Points}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Polyline Margin="20">
                                    <Polyline.Points>
                                        <Point X="{Binding X}"/>
                                        <Point Y="{Binding Y }"/>
                                    </Polyline.Points>
                                </Polyline>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

The Probelm is for some reason the datatempalte got totally ignored.
The WPF is shown in my uercontroll with ever polyline i added to Measurements but never throu my datatemplate.

Comment: This XAML would create a Polyline with two points for each element in the Points collection. The first Point would only have its X value set, the second only Y. This does not seem to make sense.

Comment: A `Polyline`'s `Points` property can be bound to a `System.Windows.Media.PointCollection` object.  If you can change your `ObservableCollection<Point>` object to instead be a `PointCollection`, that would work.  However you would not be able to individually Add/Remove points.  Instead you would need to completely replace the `PointCollection` object every time it needs to change.  Is that acceptable for your application?

Comment: Are you sure that'll work Joe?

Comment: The `Polyline.Points` property is a `DependencyProperty`.  So it can be bound.  And the type of object it binds to is `PointCollection`.   So as long as you replace the entire `PointCollection` object every time you need to change one point, why wouldn't it work?  I didn't sit down and write a test application or anything but I would be quite surprised if it did not work.

Comment: If you have multiple polylines then you should  bind your `ItemsControl` to an `ObservableCollection` of objects that each, individually, represents one polyline.  (For example, call it "PolylineViewModel").  Then, each `PolyLineViewModel` would expose a `PointCollection` of points for just that one `Polyline`.  The `ItemsControl` can bind to an ObservableCollection but the `Polyline` needs to bind to a `PointCollection`

Comment: @Joe add/remove single points is not important. important is the binding to X and Y for me.
But it dont know if I explained it wright. I have Multiple Polylines so there will be Multiple PointCollections. But i will test it tommorow any way

Comment: You can't bind a pointcollection to the itemssource of an itemscontrol like you have. You need to bind points of a/each polyline to a pointcollection.  No binding of x any y, they come from the points in your pointcollection. If you want multiple polylines then you could bind a list or observablecollection of pointcollection to an itemssource of an itemscontrol.

Comment: @Andy so its even with the Pointcollection I wont be able to bind some how to X and Y?
@ Joe working with a PolylineVM + Pointcollection works quiete well but as seeen above i dont know how to bind from the collection to X and Y of the single points.

Comment: You have the x any set on each point in your point collection. Why do you think you need to bind them?

Comment: @Andy I use the polylines for a kind of scope in an area where i cant use beloved nuget's.
I want to present the scoped data in logarythmic, linear, half logarythmic ect. So i thought the smartest way would be to use converters for X and Y axis. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow but you can't bind x and y with a polyline. Maybe inject a function into a factory class to create the point collection's. You can bind x and y on the item container to position the entire line. Maybe that would help a bit.